# How can I make a box automatically move down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**URL**: http://test.getfamo.us/buy-twitter-followers.html

**Issue**: This post is regarding the drop down boxes, they currently are fixed in place. I would like it so they are directly under each other, and then when you click expand on one the other is pushed down. How would i go about doing this?

**Setup**: Each box is its own div (box1 through to box6), and this is in two divs (top and bottom (for the corresponding row), this is then inside an about div.

**CSS**: This is the CSS I used: http://test.getfamo.us/css/screen.css

Im fairly certain there should be a way to do it with less code as well. But anyway Im more worried about having it so the box below moves down when the box expands. The code in question is under "/* ABOUT  */" so if you search for that it should come up.

Thanks very much for any help offered! (expand coded in jquery if relevant)

Comment: I hope I understand you... :)
Than you  need  to separate your drop downs on 3 columns so  place 3 di inside one within style "float:left", than in each div place  2 drop downs... in this case when you expand one of the  drop down it will effect only on current column

Comment: I mean so when I expand the top div, the bottom div then moves down automatically :) as currently it stays in place. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: oh, this is because your "position: absolute;" at #box try use float:left instead

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of something like an accordion? [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/93b9P/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>1,000 Followers - $4.99</h3>
  <div>
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Try us out now!</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> 24 hour Delivery</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> 24/7 Live Support</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Impress your followers</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/a/L/8/a/Z/orange-cross-md.png' />Bulk Discount</div> 
  </div>
  <h3>5,000 Followers, $12.99</h3>
  <div>
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> 24 hour Delivery</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Live Support</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Get recognized now!</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Money back guartantee</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Great value</div>  
  </div>
  <h3>25,000 Followers, $29.99</h3>
  <div>
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> 24 hour Delivery</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Great for expanding business!</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Live Support</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Amazing Price</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Bulk Discount</div>  
  </div>   
  <h3>50,000 Followers, $49.99</h3>
  <div>
  <div>
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> 24 hour Delivery</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Lifetime support</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Bulk discount</div>  
    <div><img src='http://www.ibcs-software.com/images/tick.png' /> Be famous on twitter</div>  
  </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, however im wanting it for the information boxes not the price table :) this is exactly the kind of info i needed though!